# How to handle download popup and save the word file automatically in desired folder in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I have used below code but it does not work for me. It stop when download pop up occur. I want it should select "Save" button and click OK button to download file.

Please see the below code.Any one please help get the asked solution.

public static String downloadPath = "//location of folder";

```
public static FirefoxProfile FirefoxDriverProfile() throws Exception {
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",
            false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveFile",
            "application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/msword,application/xml");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting",
            true);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",
            true);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);

    return profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following -

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.animateNotifications", "false");
```

Change *application/x-shockwave-flash* to type of files you will be downloading.

Comment: Did you change the type of file? What did you change it to?

Comment: Hi Vikas Neha Ojha, I did like "profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/msword,application/xml");" It does not work for me!

Comment: profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword,application/xml,application/octet-stream");